# Rerouting to a View using RouteValueDictionary results in to many redirects...MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

When a session has expired, I want to redirect the user back to the login page. So i added a class and inherited from the ActionFilterAttribute so i can check anytime an action is about to be executed. As a test I put this code in:

```
 public class SessionFilters : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
          var defaults = new RouteValueDictionary {{"Controller", "Home"}, {"Action", "About"}};
          filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(defaults);
          base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
  }
```

As you can see, i'm forcing a redirect to the About view, but i get the following error in my browser:

```
  The webpage at http://localhost:58494/Home/About has resulted in too many redirects.
  Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the 
  problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and 
  not a problem with your computer.
```

How do i properly redirect to another view using this method? Thanks

**UPDATE** Nevermind. I had a Homer simpson moment. What I have defined is an infinite loop so the browser was like "forget this". The code is working ..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you didn't decorate the entire HomeController with the `[SessionFilters]` attribute but only the action that needs to redirect to about. If you decorated the entire controller with the action filter then obviously this filter applies to all actions including About and thus the infinite redirect loop.